# Attempt to read a non-existent global 'PROXY' Lua

Tags: http, lua

I'm a newbie with Lua could someone explain an error?

I'm trying to use:

```lua
local jid_bare = require "util.jid".bare;
local http = require "socket.http";
local json_encode = require "util.json";
local mime = require("mime")
```

And when the code is execute I receive the following warning followed with stacktrace:

```
Attempt to read a non-existent global 'PROXY'
stack traceback:
    /usr/share/lua/5.1/socket/http.lua:189: in function 'adjusturi'
    /usr/share/lua/5.1/socket/http.lua:247: in function 'adjustrequest'
    /usr/share/lua/5.1/socket/http.lua:295: in function 'trequest'
    /usr/share/lua/5.1/socket/http.lua:345: in function </usr/share/lua/5.1/socket/http.lua:331>
... and so on
```

I do not using any proxy, so how can I fix it?

Comment: I think this is prosody locking globals on you. Is there a reason you are trying to use luasocket's http module instead of the prosody http stuff? Also does that error come from that require code or from some other code?

Comment: I use luasockets because I need to send POST to the external API server with some data. And I'm really sorry but I don't understand the second question. I'm trying to make module to forward some data to the external API and it seems to be working but I get this warning in logs.

Comment: There bug in LuaSocket rc1. It already fixed in master. Try just replace http.lua with new one.

Comment: I fixed that bug actually :) https://github.com/diegonehab/luasocket/commit/1f9ccb2b586c3a7e29db3c99a23ac1cee6907cf2 The Prosody developers should update their LuaSocket. In the meantime the `rawset` workaround works.

Comment: Actually no version was released with that fix yet, see https://github.com/diegonehab/luasocket/issues/110

Answer (score 6):

I'm just talk about it with Prosody developers. It is just a Prosody-specific warning and can be silenced by adding `rawset(_G, "PROXY", false)` inside the module.